# How does docker prevent root from reading from block device?

Tags: security, docker, block-device, container

I'm trying to understand Linux container security. I have a docker container running with a root shell in it. The container does not have block devices visible in `/dev`, but I can create them with `mknod`. When I then try to read from the block device (which corresponds to my primary partition) with `file -s /dev/vda1`, it says `vda1: no read permission`.

What kernel level security system prevents me from reading block devices? I had assumed this was a capability, but it is not.

Answer (score 1):

The cgroup devices controller controls access to raw devices. Based on type (character or block), major and minor device numbers it allows you to specify read, write and create rights. Docker by default does not allow read and write to most devices.

In cgroup-v2 the device controller is removed, instead you can attach an eBPF program to a cgroup to decide device access. I'm curious how readable/discoverable that is going to be.